# ViewPager not showing all Fragments added using FragmentPagerAdapter in TabLayout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a custom FragmentPagerAdapter that im using to load two fragments to a ViewPager with corresponding tab titles in a TabLayout, however, only one fragment is being displayed when i run the code, but both fragment titles appear on the tab. At first, both fragments were not displaying, then i downgraded my gradle dependencies to v7 23.0.1 for both support:appcompat and support:design and my compile version to 23. After doing that, only one fragment is showing and the stacktrace is silent. Both fragments are ListFragments(from support library).

**EDIT:** First Fragment is appearing in second Fragment's position, and Second Fragment is not being displayed at all

ViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private final List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> fragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager){super(manager);}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return fragmentTitles.get(position);
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){
    fragments.add(fragment);
    fragmentTitles.add(title);
} 
}
```

TabbedActivity.java:

```
public class TabbedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolBar;
ViewPager viewPager;
TabLayout tabLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);

    toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolBar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);


    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    //Appearing in 2nd fragment position
    adapter.addFragment(new FirstFragment(), "Frag 1");

    //Not appearing
    adapter.addFragment(new SecondFragment(), "Frag 2");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}

}
```

FirstFragment.java

```
public class FirstFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String[] from = {"_id", "name"};
    int[] to = {R.id.lvtextViewTwo, R.id.lvtextViewOne};
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_view_layout, null, from, to, 0);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Uri uri = DatabaseContentProvider.CUSTOMER_URI;
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri, null, null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    adapter.swapCursor(data);


}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
}
}
```

SecondFragment.java:

```
public class SecondFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String[] from = {"_id", "name"};
    int[] to = {R.id.lvtextViewTwo, R.id.lvtextViewOne};
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_view_layout, null, from, to, 0);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_fragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Uri uri = DatabaseContentProvider.ORDER_URI;
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri, null, null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    adapter.swapCursor(data);

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
}
}
```

PS:New to SO, please let me know if I've left anything out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem was calling `getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);` with the same `ID(0)` from both `Fragments`. Solution was to give each `initLoader` call a unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

Populate your `List` of `Fragments` inside `FragmentPagerAdapter` or pass pre-populated `List` through `constructor` to the `adapter`

```
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager)
{
    super(manager);

//Title 'Frag 1' shows, but not actual fragment
    addFragment(new FirstFragment(), "Frag 1");

    //Both title and fragment show
    addFragment(new SecondFragment(), "Frag 2");


}
```

OR

```
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager, List<Fragment> fragments)
{
    super(manager);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}
```

Comment: @VernonCliveKawonza Are you sure your Loader in Second Fragment is not returning empty data set? If you can swipe between two tabs easily, that means both fragments are there.

Comment: Checked that aswell. Launched each fragment in activity to make sure they were working properly. Please see edits

Comment: @VernonCliveKawonza that is strange. Can you debug your List to see what is placed at position 0? Also one more thing, add another 2nd fragment in tabs and then check if it appears or not.

Comment: Added another blank fragment with a single textview, 3 fragments appear but first listview is now being duplicated and second one still not showing. Double checked database, there is data at position 0. I confirmed that by launching listviews in separate activities

Comment: Solved it. Was using the same ID for each call to getSupportLoader.initLoader

Comment: @VernonCliveKawonza great